# How to have a single unique value in a column while other values are not unique?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a table with a column called force_display. This column is 1 character long and takes either a Y or N.
I want to be able to enter as many N as I want but have a constraint where a Y can only exists once in that table. Does anyone know how to achieve this or is it not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with a partial unique index:

```
create unique index uidx on tablename(force_display) where force_display='Y';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even think about trying this, probably because I didn't know the where clause could be used in index creation. Thanks again

Comment: Would it possible to expand on this and create an index which would for example keep the number of Y to let say no more than 3?

Comment: @Crouzilles: no I don't think an index-based technique could enforce `N` max rows where `N>1`

Comment: @Crouzilles You'd need a trigger that `LOCK`s the table and then counts for that, I think. Beware of lock upgrade deadlock risks with that approach though.

Comment: Thank you all for the extra info provided, very much appreciated. Regards